# Zxing 1.7 And Android API 15 -Scanner Crashing the App on Motorola device

Tags: android, zxing

I have Zxing 1.7 and Android api 15. Integrated the scanner through Intent and added CaptureActivity so that application does not ask for which camera to use.Created core.jar and added it in Android project lib and added Zxing Android as library project to my project build path.
The scanner does not work and application crashes first time when i click on "san" tab of my app but next time the same functionality it works when i login back in my app and barcode can be scanned. 
When the application crashes for first time it give ClassNot Found exception for CaptureActivity . I have followed all the requires steps and also added CaptureActivity in the Manifst.xml file.
Please advice as i have tried lots of alternatives. Does Zxing works only with Android API9 that is made obsolete now and its replacement is 10? Below is code for my ScanActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    //Scan code
    Intent intent= new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");

    //To aviod the complete action using dialog box
    intent.setClassName(this, "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"); 

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );

    //getApplicationContext().startActivity( intent );
    //View scanView = ((ActivityGroup) context).getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

    /*
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage( "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" );
    i.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
    startActivityForResult( i, 0);
    */
   }

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
  {
    System.out.println("ScanRewardCodeActivity OnActivityResult Method");
    if(requestCode == 0)
    {
      //Stop QR Code Reader intent
      finishActivity( 0 );

      TabActivity tabActivity = (TabActivity)getParent();
      TabHost tabHost = tabActivity.getTabHost();

      if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       System.out.println("Done");
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here.

- If you are using Intents, you do not need `core/` or `android/` code. Make sure to remove all of this code from your project as I think it is interfering and causing the crash.
- You should not modify your `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Yes zxing 1.7 works with all versions through to 4.0.x, but, you should use zxing 2.0 which was released a few days ago
- Don't try to write your own integration code. Use the code given in `android-integration/` as it definitely works

Comment: Thanks Sean for advice, Iam new Android Developer and followed link http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/.
In your comment you said to remove core/and android/ but how can i initiate Scan activity? I have scan tab onChange of which i call ScanActivity code that i have copied above. Are you suggesting to modify above code onCreate() method?

Comment: This is all you need, and nothing else: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Thanks a lot..I got what you were saying..Now Iam also trying the NON Intent way, like i said i followed the link http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/
 and below is code onCreate and handle the result, but getting CaptureActivity not found error. i have used zxing 1.7 and Android SDK 15. 
 Intent intent= new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.setClassName(this, "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"); 
    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );

Comment: You're mixing up two entirely different things. We *strongly* discourage the copy and paste approach from this blog post, so I will not help you proceed this way.

Comment: Sean, sorry for confusion. Yes, i did stated 2 different things, but the code i copied isfrom my app and that code was working with zxing 1.7 and Android SDK 9 and was developed by my colleague. Now I need to modify few of things in app and hence took code from repository and worked on zxing 1.7 and SDK 15. But got CaptureActivity not found error. Thus started looking at Intent way to integrate it. But i still did not understand why non intent way did not work. 
Anyways Thanks a lot for your time and prompt help.